# QML: set smooth painting

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

While playing with QML I noticed a strange behavior. Let's say I have simple QML code:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width:200
    height:100
    color:"yellow"
    border.color: "green"
    border.width: 10
    rotation: 190    
}
```

And the result:

[image: not smoothed rectangle]

The image looks poor, especially the border.
But if I add `radius: 1` I get a very different picture:

[image: smoothed rectangle]

Now it looks much better. the border also looks more smoother. Btw, setting `smooth` property do nothing. It looks that setting `radius` switches on some internal smoothing. So my question - how can I set this `smooth` without setting `radius`?

I use Qt 5.4 on Debian 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you need to set is `antialiasing`.  This is [documented here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html#antialiasing-prop):

> antialiasing : bool
>
> Used to decide if the Rectangle should use antialiasing or not.
>   Antialiasing provides information on the performance implications of
>   this property.
>
> **The default is true for Rectangles with a radius, and false otherwise.**

(Emphasis mine.)